# How to get the cast for a pointer from the pointer type

Tags: c++11, casting

This is the situation:

```
{
   MyStruct * foo;
   // works perfectly! When I change MyStruct to MyOtherStruct then
   // I do not have to change the sizeof expression.
   foo = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(decltype(*foo)));
   // The cast has to be adapted.
}
```

How can I achieve this general syntax also for the cast `(MyStruct *)`? I tried a lot but without luck.

Using C++11

**Update:**
According to *Igor Tandetnik* I *could* use `new`. How ever, I would like to know how to get the cast for a pointer from the pointer type.

Comment: `auto foo = new MyStruct;` Why are you using `malloc` with C++11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
foo = (decltype(foo)) malloc(sizeof(decltype(*foo)));
```

And as @Quentin pointed, the second `decltype` could be omitted:

```
foo = (decltype(foo)) malloc(sizeof(*foo));
```

Comment: The second `decltype` is superfluous -- `sizeof` can take an expression as operand.

Comment: OK. Sometimes I think too complicated! Answer accepted! Now when I see it, it is totally clear: `foo` is already a pointer to `MyStruct` and therefore `decltype` returns the correct type!